# Как быстро рассчитать медиану фрейма данных на скользящем окне данных?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, оптимизация

Генерирую случайный датасет и на скользящем окне в 1000 значений считаю медиану:

```
%%time
sr = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,100, size=20000)) 
for i in range(10): 
    sr.rolling(1000).apply(lambda x: np.median(x))
```

Результат:

> Wall time: 28.8 s

Целых 3 секунды на 1 проход. Подобных вычислений нужно много. Да и реальный датасет 0.5М строк, а не 20к.

Как считать скользящую медиану быстрее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь встроенными методами Pandas:

```
In [265]: %timeit sr.rolling(1000).median()
14.4 ms ± 513 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [266]: %timeit sr.rolling(1000).apply(lambda x: np.median(x))
1.72 s ± 88.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

на моем ноуте разница в 119 раз...

PS также возникает вопрос - зачем делать это много раз? Если речь идет о медианных значениях разных столбцов в одном скользящем окне, то это тоже делается векторизированными методами Pandas **без циклов**.

Comment: благодарю. Ускорилось в 80 раз. В который раз выручаете1. А как сделать для всего датафрейма? также df.rolling(1000).median()?

Comment: `df.rolling(1000).median()` - да, именно так. Здесь документация - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas.DataFrame.rolling

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста есть метод также быстро распределить данные между 0 и 1 (нормализовать )также на скользящем окне. В документации не нашла

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, можете задать новый вопрос с небольшим примером входных данных и результатом который вы хотите получить? Так не совсем понятно как и где вы хотите распределять данные